# Cannot implicitly convert type object to string in PrivateObject in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing

From what I read, I can pass in an object for the parameters in a `PrivateObject` object. The code gives the error in the description.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    MessageToSend message = new MessageToSend();
    Sender sender = new Sender(null, null, null);
    var dto = new DateTimeOffset();

    PrivateObject pObj = new PrivateObject(typeof(Sender));

    Object[] args = new Object[] { "Hello", "Marc", "Perry", dto };
    string result = pObj.Invoke("ParseBody", args);
}
```

**Error**

> Cannot implicitly convert type object to string

The method it is calling is

```
private string ParseBody(string sBody, string sFirstName, string sLastName, DateTimeOffset? tSourceTimeInfo)
```

Comment: **Pro Tip**, paste everything you need into the question, clearly identify the line that is causing the error. Since it is most likely `pObj.Invoke` calling `ParseBody` of `Sender` put in all relevant information we would need to work out whats going on, for instance like the signature of `ParseBody` in `Sender`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`PrivateObject.Invoke` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privateobject.invoke?view=mstest-net-1.2.0#Microsoft_VisualStudio_TestTools_UnitTesting_PrivateObject_Invoke_System_String_System_Object___) takes `object[]` arguments and returns `object`, so it can cope with most things. The compiler doesn't trust `object` to be a `string`, as while that may be true at runtime, it isn't true for the compiler.

So... you'll need to cast explicitly:

```
string result = (string)pObj.Invoke("ParseBody", args);
```